# Count values inside a specific array length

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm searching for a nice approach for the following task: I have a game with rounds. In each round we have a number between 1-10.

This is how I'm doing it so far but I'm stuck.

```
gameValues.forEach(function(x) { counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0)+1; });
```

I want to count the double entrees in my array but I only want to watch out for the last 5 rounds.

```
Round 6 ( We already have 5 values ):
gameValues = [9,9,9,2,1]
result: 9:3, 2:1, 1:1,

Round 7 ( Now we have 6 values but I only want to count the first 5):
gameValues = [3,9,9,9,2,1]
result: 3:1, 9:3, 2:1,
```

I can't manage to only count the last 5 rounds..

Comment: You could use [`slice()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp) to create an array of the last five rounds and then loop through that with `forEach`. Or you could make a `for` loop, which loops through the last 5 rounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) the array before looping through it.

```
gameValues.slice(-5).forEach(function(x) { counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0)+1; });
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `gameValues.slice(-5)` to get the last 5 values of the array, then do the same count operation :

```js
gameValues = [3,9,9,9,2,1]
counts = {}
gameValues.slice(-5).forEach(function(x) { counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0)+1; });
console.log(counts);
// { '1': 1, '2': 1, '9': 3 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the last 5 numbers in an array using [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) and then using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) you can get the counts of each number.

> The splice() method changes the contents of an array by removing or
> replacing existing elements and/or adding new elements in place. To
> access part of an array without modifying it, see slice().

```js
function countLastFive(arr) {
  return arr.splice(-5).reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc[curr] = acc[curr] ? ++acc[curr] : 1;
    return acc;
  }, {});
}

console.log(countLastFive([9, 9, 9, 2, 1, 3, 1]));
console.log(countLastFive([9, 9, 9, 2, 1]));
console.log(countLastFive([3, 9, 9, 9, 2, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1]));
```

**Just be sure that the slice changes the original array. So it would be better to clone the array so that It won't change the original array**

```js
function countLastFive(arr) {
  return arr.splice(-5).reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc[curr] = acc[curr] ? ++acc[curr] : 1;
    return acc;
  }, {});
}

const arr1 = [9, 9, 1, 9, 2, 1];
const arr2 = [9, 9, 1, 9, 2, 1];

console.log("Before -> arr1 => ", arr1);
console.log(countLastFive(arr1));
console.log("After -> arr1 => ", arr1);

console.log("Before -> arr2 => ", arr2);
console.log(countLastFive([...arr2]));
console.log("After -> arr2 => ", arr2);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const gameValues = [3,9,9,9,2,1]
    
const uniq = gameValues.splice(-5)
  .map((number) => {
    return {
      count: 1,
      number: number
  }})
  .reduce((a, b) => {
    a[b.number] = (a[b.number] || 0) + b.count
    return a
  }, {})
 
console.log(uniq);
```